# i have to list all images,backgrounds, layers etc inside my video as json file using ffmpeg

Tags: json, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Please tell me the ffmpeg cammand line code to get information of mp4 file in json format. i want details of video(in mp4) to json format. The details include images, layers , background, audio information etc just as shown in code below.(The output is show below i need input command line code).Thanks in advance

```
{  
   "images":[
{
  "name":"img_0.jpg",
  "w":540,
  "h":960,
  "prefix":[
    "-i"
  ],
  "postfix":[

  ]
},
{
  "name":"img_1.jpg",
  "w":540,
  "h":960,
  "prefix":[
    "-i"
  ],
  "postfix":[

  ]
},
{
  "name":"img_2.jpg",
  "w":540,
  "h":960,
  "prefix":[
    "-i"
  ],
  "postfix":[

  ]
},
{
  "name":"img_3.jpg",
  "w":540,
  "h":960,
  "prefix":[
    "-i"
  ],
  "postfix":[

  ]
},
{
  "name":"img_4.jpg",
  "w":540,
  "h":960,
  "prefix":[
    "-i"
  ],
  "postfix":[

  ]
}
],
"static_inputs":[
{
  "name":"background_video.mp4",
  "prefix":[
    "-i"
  ],
  "postfix":[

  ]
}
],
 "video":{
"h":960,
"w":1080,
"duration":30
},
"e":[],
"m":[
"-{pythoncomplex}"
],
"r":["[5]split=2[color][alpha]; [color]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[color]; [alpha]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:0[alpha]; 
[color][alpha]{pythonmerge}[ovrly]; [0]scale=540:960,setsar=1[0_scalled]; 
[1]scale=540:960,setsar=1[1_scalled]; [2]scale=540:960,setsar=1[2_scalled]; 
[3]scale=540:960,setsar=1[3_scalled]; [4]scale=540:960,setsar=1[4_scalled]; [0_scalled] 
{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.1,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*5:s=540x960, 
{pythonf}=t=out:st=6:d=1[v0]; [1_scalled]{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.1,max(1.001, 
{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*5:s=540x960,{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=6:d=1[v1]; 
[2_scalled]{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.1,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*7:s=540x960, 
{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=8:d=1[v2]; [3_scalled] 
{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.1,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*7:s=540x960, 
{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=8:d=1[v3]; [4_scalled] 
{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.1,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*6:s=540x960, 
{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=7:d=1[v4]; [v0][v1][v2][v3] 
[v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[concatenated_video]; [concatenated_video][ovrly] 
{pythono}=0:0[base_video]; [base_video][6] 
{pythono}=enable='between(t,0,15)':x=30:y=30[watermarked_part1]; [watermarked_part1][6] 
{pythono}=enable='between(t,15,30)':x=(main_w-{pythono}_w-30):y=(main_h-{pythono}_h-30)"],
"i":["[5]split=2[color][alpha]; [color]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[color]; [alpha]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:0[alpha]; 
[color][alpha]{pythonmerge}[ovrly]; [0]scale=540:960,setsar=1[0_scalled]; 
[1]scale=540:960,setsar=1[1_scalled]; [2]scale=540:960,setsar=1[2_scalled]; 
[3]scale=540:960,setsar=1[3_scalled]; [4]scale=540:960,setsar=1[4_scalled]; [0_scalled] 
{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.1,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*5:s=540x960, 
{pythonf}=t=out:st=6:d=1[v0]; [1_scalled]{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.1,max(1.001, 
{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*5:s=540x960,{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=6:d=1[v1]; 
[2_scalled]{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.1,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*7:s=540x960, 
{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=8:d=1[v2]; [3_scalled] 
{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.1,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*7:s=540x960, 
{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=8:d=1[v3]; [4_scalled] 
{pythonz}pan=z='if(lte({pythonz},1.0),1.1,max(1.001,{pythonz}-0.0015))':d=25*6:s=540x960, 
{pythonf}=t=in:st=0:d=1,{pythonf}=t=out:st=7:d=1[v4]; [v0][v1][v2][v3] 
[v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[concatenated_video]; [concatenated_video][ovrly] 
{pythono}=0:0[base_video]; [base_video][6] 
{pythono}=enable='between(t,0,15)':x=30:y=30[watermarked_part1]; [watermarked_part1][6] 
{pythono}=enable='between(t,15,30)':x=(main_w-{pythono}_w-30):y=(main_h-{pythono}_h-30) 
[final_video]"],
"n":[],
"g":[],
"c":[],
"o":[
"-map",
"[final_video]",
"-map",
"7:a"
],
"d":[
"-t",
"30"
],
"s":[],
 "layers": [
{
  "ao": 0,
  "bm": 1,
  "ddd": 0,
  "ind": 1,
  "ip": 0,
  "ks": {
    "a": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 1,
      "k": [
        270,
        480,
        0
      ]
    },
    "o": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 11,
      "k": 18.039
    },
    "p": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 2,
      "k": [
        270,
        480,
        0
      ]
    },
    "r": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 10,
      "k": 0
    },
    "s": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 6,
      "k": [
        100,
        100,
        100
      ]
    }
  },
  "nm": "all",
  "op": 327,
  "refId": "image_0",
  "sr": 1,
  "st": 0,
  "ty": 2
},
{
  "ao": 0,
  "bm": 3,
  "ddd": 0,
  "ind": 2,
  "ip": 76,
  "ks": {
    "a": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 1,
      "k": [
        270,
        480,
        0
      ]
    },
    "o": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 11,
      "k": 40
    },
    "p": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 2,
      "k": [
        270,
        480,
        0
      ]
    },
    "r": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 10,
      "k": 0
    },
    "s": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 6,
      "k": [
        100,
        100,
        100
      ]
    }
  },
  "nm": "lvjing  all 3",
  "op": 327,
  "refId": "image_1",
  "sr": 1,
  "st": -8,
  "ty": 2
},
{
  "ao": 0,
  "bm": 13,
  "ddd": 0,
  "ind": 3,
  "ip": 76,
  "ks": {
    "a": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 1,
      "k": [
        270,
        480,
        0
      ]
    },
    "o": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 11,
      "k": 50.196
    },
    "p": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 2,
      "k": [
        270,
        480,
        0
      ]
    },
    "r": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 10,
      "k": 0
    },
    "s": {
      "a": 0,
      "ix": 6,
      "k": [
        100,
        100,
        100
      ]
    }
  },
  "nm": "baohedu all 3",
  "op": 327,
  "refId": "image_2",
  "sr": 1,
  "st": -8,
  "ty": 2
}
]
}
```

Comment: What are "layers"? What is the meaning of  `ao`, `bm`, `ddd`, `ind`, ...?

Comment: Can you tell me? How you have got this command?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Not possible. MP4 does not contain "layers". It can only contain video, audio, and subtitles. Not distinct images, backgrounds, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the video information in a json file using below command

```
    ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams "input.mp4" >output.json
```

you can see the sample output from   [this link](https://jsonkeeper.com/b/62WD)
let me know if you have anything to know more

Comment: this command not exporting json as above. It just print media information.

Comment: I think your question is not clear to me. Can you add some more insights to your question

Answer (score 0):

Use `ffprobe` with `-print_format json` and `>` to redirect output to a file:

`ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams "video.mp4" > ffprobe_output.json`

Note that `>` is a a Linux program, not a function of `ffprobe`.

Comment: can't get this output can you tell me how to get above json from video.

Comment: This code works.
Instead of downvoting, show us your output!
You can download this test video https://samples.ffmpeg.org/mov/canon_6d/mvi_9112.mov and try it.

Comment: this command not exporting json as above. It just print media information.

Comment: I've edited my answer according to your suggestion.